# Electron: change page (html) without getting a white screen while loading (in the same window)

Tags: node.js, electron

I want to know if there is a way to load an html page (navigate between pages in the same window) without getting a flashing white screen, the 'ready-to-show' method doesn't seem to work for me.

```
var win2 = remote.getCurrentWindow({ backgroundColor: "#578985", show: false });

win2.loadURL(
  url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, "./all-student.html"),
    protocol: "file",
    slashes: true,
  })
);

win2.once("ready-to-show", function () {
  win2.show();
  console.log("not showing");
});
```